# How do functions with a function pointer as an argument accept it if it is uninitialized?

Tags: c, function-pointers

How does the function pointer in the declaration of any_function receive any value? In the main function, any_function is never given any function pointers, only functions themselves. Does this mean the function pointer any_function is recursively calling itself?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum(int, int);
int product(int, int);
int difference(int, int);
int any_function(int(*pfun)(int, int), int x, int y);

int main(void)
{
  int a = 10; /* Initial value for a */
  int b = 5; /* Initial value for b */
  int result = 0; /* Storage for results */
  int (*pf)(int, int) = sum; /* Pointer to function */

  /* Passing a pointer to a function */
  result = any_function(pf, a, b);
  printf("\nresult = %d", result );

  /* Passing the address of a function */
  result = any_function(product,a, b);
  printf("\nresult = %d", result );
  printf("\nresult = %d\n", any_function(difference, a, b));

  return 0;
}

/* Definition of a function to call a function */
int any_function(int(*pfun)(int, int), int x, int y)
{
  return pfun(x, y);
}
/* Definition of the function sum */
int sum(int x, int y)
{
  return x + y;
}

/* Definition of the function product */
int product(int x, int y)
{
  return x * y;
}

/*Defintion of the function product*/
int difference(int x, int y)
{
  return x - y;
}
```

Comment: It's being given `pf`, which is set to `sum`.

Comment: Again?! [Didn't I just explain to you that a *function designator* is implicitly converted to a pointer to a function in almost all cases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54820263/why-can-function-pointers-be-used-with-or-without-the-address-of-operator)

Comment: *"In the main function, `any_function` is never given any function pointers, only functions themselves."* False, the first call to `any_function` explicitly passes a function pointer. The other two calls implicitly pass function pointers. *"Does this mean the function pointer `any_function` is recursively calling itself?"* No, definitely not.

Comment: The question might be clearer if you remove two of the calls to `any_function`. See [mcve].

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Whoa, yes this is in fact the same problem I keep forgetting. Okay I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does the function pointer in the declaration of any_function receive any value?

Because the function call specified a value. Same as any other parameter.

E.g. when you write:

```
int my_function(int x) {
    return x + 1;
}

// in main
printf("%d\n", my_function(5));
```

it prints 6. But how did `x` in the declaration of `my_function` receive any value? Well, it was specified when we wrote `my_function(5)`.

> In the main function, any_function is never given any function pointers, only functions themselves.

If you use a function like that it is converted to a pointer automatically. In other words `pf = sum;` is short for `pf = &sum;`

> Does this mean the function pointer any_function is recursively calling itself?

No, where did that idea come from?